# Codename One: constraints (West, center...) not visible in new GUI Builder

Tags: codenameone

The window where the constraints of the Border Layout should show, is empty? Note: of course my Form is selected before I switched to the Layout panel.

->
[image]

Comment: What's the hierarchy to reproduce this consistently?
Make sure you select the right component within the tree to make this happen.

Comment: I just select the Form, which I want to put in Border Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the child component that you want centered not the parent container.

I think this will become more intuitive when we split the tree out of the tabs UI so you can always see it like we could in the old GUI builder. Ideally we should also be able to drag into the tree like we could back then.

[image]

[image]